# Select User data from the combination of four tables

Tags: sql, doctrine-orm

I have multiple tables such as 
Its a bit complex matter.

1)Normal user table

```
User 
id|username
0 |Tom     
1 |Dad
2 |Bob
```

2)Two tables for area

```
SmallArea
id|name   |bigarea
0 |blockA | 0(prefA)
1 |blockB | 0(prefA)
2 |blockC | 1(prefB)
3 |blockD | 1(prefB)
4 |blockE | 2(prefC)
```

3)Two tables for area

```
BigArea
id | name
0  | prefA
1  | prefB
2  | prefC
```

it means

blockA and blockB belong to prefA

blockC and blockD belong to prefB

blockE belongs to prefC

4)User and small area connection table

```
AreaConnection 
user_id|smallarea
0(Tom) | 0(blockA)
0(Tom) | 1(blockB)
1(Dad) | 2(blockC)
1(Dad) | 3(blockD)
2(Bob) | 3(blockD)
```

it means

Tom belong to blockA and blockB

Dad belongs to blockC and blockD

Bob belongs to blockD

then
Assume, I have BigArea key 0(it means prefB)

I want to select the users which belongs to the blocks which belongs to bigarea named prefB.

(prefB has blockC and blockD,

then Dad and Bob are belongs to blockC or blockD,

so Dad and Bob should be selected)

How could I write this pattern in SQL?
Doctrine2 is better such as

```
SELECT u.id,u.username
           FROM User u 
            INNER JOIN ??????
```

These are my Entities.

```
class User.php
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer",unique=true)
 * @ORM\Id
 */

private $id;


 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */ 
private $username;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\SmallArea")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="areaid", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */

protected $SmallArea;
}




class BigArea
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer",unique=true)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $id;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */ 
private $label;

/**
*
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\SmallArea", mappedBy="prefecture")
*/

private $prefecture;

}




class SmallArea{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */ 
private $label;


  /**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\BigArea",     inversedBy="prefecture*removethis : name of the variable in BigArea.php*")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id",nullable=false)
 */
private $prefecture;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select *
from User
Inner Join AreaConnection on AreaConnection.userid = User.id
Inner Join SmallArea on SmallArea on SmallArea.id = AreaConnection.smallarea
Inner Join BigArea on BigArea.id = SmallArea.bigarea
```

Doctrine DQL. Kindly take note that I never tried this, but it seems similiar to Hibernate.
For more, refer to [Doctrine ORM Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/index.html)

```
Select u.username, sa.label
from User u
JOIN SmallArea sa
```

Comment: Thanks it works as normal SQL.But I am in trouble with translating this to doctorine2 format,,Does anyone help ?in Doctorine2 AreaConnection table is concealed.User and SmallArea Entity made this automatically.

Comment: for that you have to provide your mapping

Comment: I added my entities to the article

Comment: Edited. Pardon if its not working, but the concept should be there

Comment: Hi @Farid Mohd Nor ,thanks to your support.I can figure out the final sentence.  Select u.username,sa.label    from User u    Inner JOIN u.SmallArea sa    WHERE sa.prefecture = $x. I am surprised that Doctrine2 simplifies Normal SQL so much.